# Java selenium скачать файл dropbox

Tags: java, selenium

Java selenium скачать файл dropbox
Есть файл https://www.dropbox.com/s/5g32vht9rugmuli/TestFile.xlsx
Как мне нажать на эту http://prntscr.com/m8k2xk кнопку?
[image: Скачать Dropbox]
Чего я только не перепробовал, выдает ошибку «org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:»

Помогите пож-та
Вот мой код:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class DownloadPriceDropbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constants.pathGoogleDriver);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        try {
            driver.get("https://www.dropbox.com/s/5g32vht9rugmuli/TestFile.xlsx");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"component6061055478049640454\"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button/span/span")).click();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил свой вопрос так

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class DownloadPriceDropbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constants.pathGoogleDriver);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        try {
            driver.get("https://www.dropbox.com/s/5g32vht9rugmuli/TestFile.xlsx");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[starts-with(text(),'Скачать')]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(500);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[.='Прямое скачивание']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JFYI: Ваше решения является не переносимым, так как завязано на локализацию текста. Можете открыть на другой машине и текст будет на английском и скачивание не пройдет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно как то так:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constants.pathGoogleDriver);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        try {
            driver.get("https://www.dropbox.com/s/5g32vht9rugmuli/TestFile.xlsx");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver
                    .findElements(By.tagName("button"))
                    .stream()
                    .filter(x -> x.getAttribute("role") == "menuitem")
                    .findFirst()
             .click();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.: сорри проверить нету веозможности.